# PHP - Capitalize the first letter after a dot or after a dot and a space

Tags: php, regex, string, function, text

I would like to capitalize the first letter after a dot or after a dot and a space.

```
$string="I am a string with several periods.period #1. period #2.";
```

This should be the final string:

```
I am a string with several periods.Period #1. Period #2.
```

I have already searched for a solution on stackoverflow but the solution that i found was only for capitalize the initial letter after just a dot and not for a dot and a space.

Comment: I find the duplicate incorrect. There is nothing in that answer that even mentions the problem OP explains, the optional number of spaces.

Comment: @Andreas, you are right! I have also consulted the link of Wiktor before asking my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use regex to match the dot `\.`, optional space `\s*` and a letter `\w`.
Then loop the matches array and do a str_replace.

```
$str="I am a string with several periods.period #1. period #2.";
preg_match_all("/\.\s*\w/", $str, $matches);

foreach($matches[0] as $match){
    $str = str_replace($match, strtoupper($match), $str);
}
echo $str;
//I am a string with several periods.Period #1. Period #2.
```

https://3v4l.org/LevU5

To make it slightly more optimized you could add an array_unique before looping since str_replace replaces all equal substrings.

```
$matches[0] = array_unique($matches[0]);
```

https://3v4l.org/mIiX8

Comment: Serial downvoter in action, all answers has been downvoted at 18h05 UTC

Comment: @Toto I can bet my left arm that it's the person who had his duplicate hammer removed from this question.

Answer (score 3):

[Preg_replace_callback](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) is your friend:

```
$string="I am a string with several periods.period #1. period #2.";
$string = preg_replace_callback('/\.\s*\K\w/', 
    function($m) {
        return strtoupper($m[0]);
    },
    $string);
echo $string;
```

**Output:**

```
I am a string with several periods.Period #1. Period #2.
```

Comment: Serial downvoter in action, all answers has been downvoted at 18h05 UTC

Comment: What's going on with all the downvotes to all the answers?

Comment: Is it possible to capitalize also the first letter? Like "i am a string with several periods.period #1. period #2.";

Comment: @Memonic: Try with `/(?:^|\.\s*)\K\w/`

Answer (score 1):

I created this simple function and it works like a charm

and you can add delimiters as you like.

```
function capitalize_after_delimiters($string='', $delimiters = array())
{
    foreach ($delimiters as $delimiter)
    {
        $temp = explode($delimiter, $string);
        array_walk($temp, function (&$value) { $value = ucfirst($value); });
        $string = implode($temp, $delimiter);
    }
    return $string;
}

$string ="I am a string with several periods.period #1. period #2.";

$result = capitalize_after_delimiters($string, array('.', '. '));

var_dump($result);

result: string(56) "I am a string with several periods.Period #1. Period #2."
```

[result](https://3v4l.org/DMZ0t#output)

Comment: This solution is good but can fail in many ways. If the text has three spaces it fails (or you have to manually add it), if there is a new line after the dot it fails. https://3v4l.org/lcBZG

Comment: I solved his problem as he asked and add some extra features too, but if you want to make it **absolutely perfect solution** in general, then we can work on that.

Comment: Serial downvoter in action, all answers has been downvoted at 18h05 UTC

Answer (score 0):

If regex is not an option, something like this might work:

```
$str = "I am a string with several periods.period #1. period #2.";
$strings = explode('.', $str);
$titleCased = [];

foreach($strings as $s){
    $titleCased[] = ucfirst(trim($s));
}
echo join(".", $titleCased);
```

Although, this has the added effect of removing whitespace.

https://3v4l.org/fWGUW

Comment: the white space should remain

Comment: You could just join with `". "`  and that would make it "correct" as well. Although that may not be what OP wants though.

Comment: @Daniele if you remove `trim` you get the expected result with this code. Edit, sorry no you don't. My mistake

Comment: But this will work. https://3v4l.org/RWnfv @erickb feel free to add this to your answer if you want

Comment: Serial downvoter in action, all answers has been downvoted at 18h05 UTC